# Using Google Maps images in Arcgis Online pop-up windows

Tags: google-maps, arcgis-online, popup, image-service

I typically configure pop-ups in ArcGIS to show the image in the pop-up, by using dedicated URLs to the image which typically ends with .jpg or .png etc.

But, I am having trouble getting ArcGIS to recognize the URL to images hosted on Google Maps; a URL such as (https://www.google.com/maps/uv?hl=en&pb=!1s0x94b2354a240140d:0xfab1aeb455c4b700!2m22!2m2!1i80!2i80!3m1!2i20!16m16!1b1!2m2!1m1!1e1!2m2!1m1!1e3!2m2!1m1!1e5!2m2!1m1!1e4!2m2!1m1!1e6!3m1!7e115!4shttps://picasaweb.google.com/lh/).

I do not have any coding experience.

Any ideas?